# Place an UIImage after an UILabel

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I want to have an UILabel with a max width of 100 and after that an UIImage, how can I do that in interface builder? I want that if the text is shorter the label is less than 100 but the UIImage is right behind the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with code like this:

first init the label and the imageView

```
_label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x + label.frame.size.width, label.frame.origin.y, 30, 30)];
```

then when the label has text , you can calc the width of the label`s frame

```
CGSize size = [_label.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
CGFloat width = size.width > 100 ? 100 : size.width;
CGFloat height = size.height;
_label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: Thanks, the only problem now is, the image is only on the right place after scrolling not when its in the beginning on my tableview.

Answer (score 5):

You can use **NSTextAttachment** class available from iOS 7.No need to play with the frame.

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
NSAttributedString *attachmentAttrString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];
NSMutableAttributedString *str= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"];
[str appendAttributedString:attachmentAttrString];
myLabel.attributedText = str;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add my swift solution:

```
    let label = UILabel()

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello".uppercaseString)
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = UIImage(named:"hello")

    attributedString.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(attachment:attachment))

//  use the following method to insert the image at any index
//  attributedString.insertAttributedString(NSAttributedString(attachment:attachment), atIndex: 0)

    label.attributedText = attributedString
```