# UIImage on UILabel

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uilabel

I have a UILabel on a UITableViewCell which I am reusing at multiple places. It will hold text/statements of type NSString.

***Question:*** For just one cell, I want an image before the text starts. Is it possible to place/display UIImage before text in iOS on UILabel. I can definitely place an image directly on the cell before the label, but I wish to avoid playing around with the constraints if it affects the other reusing cells.

Comment: I tried it out and this does work. However I am having a hard time to add spacing between the image and the text on the label. My requirement is to have some text after the label, but since I am unaware of how to handle the horizontal spacing, the image is been overridden by the image.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the horizontal spacing between the image and the text on UILabel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. UILabel is a subclass of UIView. Therefore, you can add anything derived from UIView to UILabel.

Below code is an example I show you.

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 20)];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bear.png"]];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);
[label addSubview:imgView];
```

I think that making a custom view which has any features you want is better than using UILabel.

Comment: @tech_learning yes. right. last statement should be changed to "[label addSubview:imgView]". i mistyped.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with **NSTextAttachment** class available from iOS 7.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30073038/4034301) is the easy answer for this

Answer (score 1):

Not in the UILabel but you can definitively do it in the Cell, you need to create a custom class that inherits from UITableViewCell.

In there define your cell at your better convenience